# Probability of blue eyes

Tags: probability

A couple has $\large {1\over4}$ chance of having a child with blue eyes. If this couple has $3$ children, what are the chances of $2$ of them have blue eyes?

It's an easy question, but I'm in doubt if the result is

> $\large{3\over 64}$ => $\large{(\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3})}$

or

> $\large{9\over 64}$ => ($3 * \dfrac{1}{3}$, because you have $3$ different combinations)

Anyone can tell me which is the right answer and why?

Comment: Do you want the probability exactly two have blue eyes, or that two or more have blue eyes?

Comment: The probability exactly two have blue eyes

Comment: probability=$(\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{4})\times \frac{3!}{2!}$. The $(\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{4})$ part caters for the combination (blue,blue,not blue) and the $\frac{3!}{2!}$ part caters for different combinations.

Comment: @K.Rmth Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: okay @amWhy . Did just that following your comment above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability=$$(\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{4})\times \frac{3!}{2!}=\frac{9}{64}$$
The $(\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{4})$  part caters for the combination (blue,blue,not blue) while the $\frac{3!}{2!}$  caters for different combinations.
Note that $\frac{3!}{2!}=3$ which is the number of possible combinations :

1. (blue,blue,not blue)
2. (blue,not blue,blue)
3. (not blue,blue,blue)

Comment: thank you, but the only thing I didn't understand is why I need to count the different combinations. Can you explain me that?

Comment: Because each combination satisfies the condition "2 children have blue eyes".